How do I dynamically render data into a html table in react?
I'm trying to render a list of to-do items in a html table in react. I'm currently doing this by iterating through my database rows for each to-do item:
todoLogs.forEach(todoLog => {
        tableHtmlContent += `
          <tr>
            <td>${todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id).title}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ${todoLog.d09_04_24 ? "checked" : "unchecked"}></input></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ${todoLog.d08_04_24 ? "checked" : "unchecked"}></input></td>
            <td><button onClick=${deleteTodo}><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button></td>
          </tr>
        `
      })

using that to update a variable that holds a template string:
  var tableHtmlContent = `
  <tr ref={tableHeaderContainer} className='border-2 border-black ml-2'>
    <th>Habit</th>
    <th>09/04</th>
    <th>08/04</th>
  </tr>
  `

and rendering that variable inside a table:
<table
        className='mt-3 border-2 [&>tr]:border-2 [&>tr>td]:border-2 [&>tr>th]:border-2 [&>tr>th]:px-1 text-center'
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: tableHtmlContent}}
      >
      </table>

What I now need to do is add onClick functionality to the button in the table, to allow me to delete todos:
<button onClick=${deleteTodo}><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>

- but at the moment this isn't working and I get the error: async is not defined
The way of doing this using template strings right now seems inefficient anyway, aside from the issue with the button, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?
Here is what the table looks like also:
Image of the table
To solve this, I've already looked into:

useRef in react

the .innerHTML() function

useState()

useEffect()


- but couldn't find anything workable. Any help would be much appreciated?

Why are you using dangerouslySetInnerHTML rather than rendering the rows with regular JSX?

you could add how the API data is structured and the expected result you wanted... there are very less scenarios where we would opt for dangerouslySetInnerHTML

@evolutionxbox it's the only thing I found that would work so far... but I highly suspect there's a better way of doing things

@KcH the data is from supabase GET requests that return an object with several attributes e.g. id, title etc.
yeah using dangerouslySetInnerHTML definitely doesn't seem optimum...

Yep @silver77 , you could add how your data looks like and the expected output ... we don't know what is required just by seeing the code

You can add HTML elements within a JSX variable like so:
var tableRows = {

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>09/03</th>
            <th>10/03</th>
            <th>11/03</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Complete</td>
            <td>Uncomplete</td>
            <td>Complete</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uncomplete</td>
            <td>Uncomplete</td>
            <td>Complete</td>
        </tr>
    </table>  

}

Then just add that variable inside another HTML element, and update it as needed with whatever features you want:
<div>
    {tableRows}
</div>


ah yeah, that makes sense tbh, dunno why that didn't occur to me
